# c# best way to get first instance of a specific string from a web response

Tags: c#, json, string

quick question:

I am using an API to create tickets and am trying to record the ticket number from the web response that is returned. It is right up in front prefixed with "number":1111 however there are other instances of "number" in the response (for example, "number of comments"). Also, the number in the future could be 5 digits instead of only 4. So in a perfect world, I need only the numbers in between number": and ,"

Here is an example/snippet of the response text:

> "{"id":99999999,"number":1234,"name":"ticket
> description","description":"\u003cp style=\"text-align:
> center;\"\u003eTicket Title
> Header\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u0026nbsp;\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eTestDescription-notes
> for
> ticket\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u0026nbsp;\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eMore
> ticket
> details\u0026nbsp;\u003c/p\u003e","description_no_html":"Ticket
> Header\n \nTicketDescription,"number_of_comments":0,"

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = output;

    streamWriter.Write(json);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    /* where I'd put the code to extract ticket number 
        string ticketNum = ???*/
}
LogWriter.LogWrite("Ticket successfully created...", logPath);
```

Comment: JSON should  be parsed with a JSON parser.

Comment: Use Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json(.net core 3.x+) to deserialize response to your object.